# Импорт контента файла в переменную TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Допустим я хочу получить контент файла в переменную таким образом:

```
import authWnd from "../../views/authWnd.html!text";
```

В typings добавил:

```
declare module "*!text" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

При компиляции получаю ошибку:

> Error:(2, 21) TS2307: Cannot find module
>   '../../views/authWnd.html!text'.

Попробовал использовать [этот плагин для systemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text), настроил так:

```
SystemJS.config({
    "defaultJSExtensions": true,
    map: {
        css: '/js/system-css.js',
        text: '/js/text.js'
    },
    meta: {
        '*.css': { loader: 'css' },
        "*.html": { loader: 'text' }
    },
// ....
```

Но толку ноль, та же ошибка, т.к. дело тут не в этом плагине точно.

Подскажите, как все же импортнуть контент файла в переменную ts?

**UPDATE:**

Если сделать так:

```
import authWnd = require("/js/views/authWnd.html!text");
```

В typings:

```
declare module "/js/views/authWnd.html!text" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

То все работает. Но почему когда я в typings так делаю: `declare module "*!text"` или `declare module "*.html"` - то получаю ошибку  `Cannot find module ...`

Как решить проблему? Это вообще возможно?

Comment: ну так, возможно, ошибка банально в неверном пути к *authWnd.html*?

Comment: @lexxl, Путь верный. Дело в том, что если делать импорт так: 
`import "../../views/authWnd.html!text";` 
то все грузится, в консоли в браузере видно что файл прогружен. А вот если так: 
`import authWnd from "../../views/authWnd.html!text";` 
то получаю ошибку компиляции ts